# Convert metrodate textbox to short date

Tags: c#

but I don't know how to remove the time by using this code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, [string format], [IFormatProvider provider]);
```

This is my code:

```
Paragraph para3 = new Paragraph(metroComboBox1.Text + " from " + 
DateTime.Parse(metroDateTime1.Text) + " to " +
DateTime.Parse(metroDateTime2.Text));
```

Comment: i only need the date .

Comment: can you post what type are your `metroDateTime` variables?

Comment: i found something but i don't know the  iformatprovider
DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, [string format],    [IFormatProvider provider]);

Comment: @meJustAndrew im just using metrodatetime1.text

Comment: How did you actually made the `metroDateTime1` object/ what is it's type or what type of application are you trying to make?

Comment: @meJustAndrew we are using third party .dll , metroframework UI

Comment: okay, then can you include the string you receive from `metroDateTime1.Text` so one could know if this can be parsed?

Comment: when i used this code
 Paragraph para3 = new Paragraph(metroComboBox1.Text + " from " + 
DateTime.Parse(metroDateTime1.Text) + " to " +
DateTime.Parse(metroDateTime2.Text));

the output is this : Consumed Materials Report from 9/1/2016 12:00:00 AM to 10/8/2016 12:00:00 AM .
 i need only is like this :Consumed Materials Report from 9/1/2016 to 10/8/2016 @meJustAndrew

Comment: which is the output? Only two points `:` ?

Comment: Why is this question tagged as an iText question? How is your question related to PDF?